# Mootools getPosition() gives wrong position

Tags: javascript, position, mootools

I have a strange problem with determining the position of elements with help of the Mootools getPosition() function. The following is the case:

I have a form, which has two tables (I know this is semantically not right, however I have to work with it):

```
<form>
    <table>
        <!-- rows, columns and finally inputs, selects and teaxtarea here -->
    </table>
    <table>
        <!-- rows, columns and finally inputs, selects and teaxtarea here -->
    </table>
</form>
```

This where Javascript with Mootools comes into play. I have a small script that displays the error of a specific form field when this field is in focus, a tooltip idea. The position of this tooltip or errortip in this case is determined in with getPosition(). This work perfectly on the first table, however when focusing on an element in the second table it is just like the height of the first table is ignored.

Here a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4BVc/6/

Comment: Exception: so.users.LowRateException has been encountered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getPosition(relative)` will return the position relative to `relative`.

Just simply change:

```
var pos = el.getPosition(el.getOffsetParent().getOffsetParent());
```

to

```
var pos = el.getPosition();
```

This will thing its position relative to the document.

Comment: Is there another way to determine the position of the elements? I see there is a parameter to give getPosition(), in order to determine the parent used for determining the position. I'll try to work woth that.

Comment: If you want to make it relative to the form just assign an id to the form and then use `el.getPosition(document.getElementById(formId))`

Comment: It seems i've discovered the reason. I was specifically using a parent already in the following way: "el.getOffsetParent.getOffsetParent". Kinda hacky, so i;m searching for a good solution to select the correct parent @MMM, yes indeed i'll try that

Comment: positioning relative to the document didn't work out. The jsfiddle is ofcourse a stripped example in which it did work. However in my specific case it didn't. My solution: "var pos = el.getPosition(el.getParent('#main'));"